# how to rewrite cache in client using tanstack query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tanstackreact-query

I want to rewrite my data and add one in client react app
but it doesn't work
please help me

```
export const usePostProduct = (): UseMutationResult<AxiosResponse<IProduct, any>, unknown, CreatingProduct, unknown> => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const query = new QueryCache()
    return useMutation(['products'], (data: CreatingProduct) => {
        return Product.addOne(data)
    }, {
        onSuccess(data) {
            
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's is `optimistic update` in `react-query` , [Docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/optimistic-updates)

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

useMutation({
  mutationFn: updateTodo,
  // When mutate is called:
  onMutate: async (newTodo) => {
    // Cancel any outgoing refetches
    // (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
    await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['todos'] })

    // Snapshot the previous value
    const previousTodos = queryClient.getQueryData(['todos'])

    // Optimistically update to the new value
    queryClient.setQueryData(['todos'], (old) => [...old, newTodo])

    // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
    return { previousTodos }
  },
  // If the mutation fails,
  // use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
  onError: (err, newTodo, context) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['todos'], context.previousTodos)
  },
  // Always refetch after error or success:
  onSettled: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['todos'] })
  },
})
```